# Azure Cloud Services Extended Support

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to implement azure cloud services extended support thorugh terraform.
I have checked the official documentation and did not find any existing code to implement it.
Can you check to let me know if it possible to implement it through terraform

Comment: for which service you want to extended support and what is this extended support?

Comment: @RahulKumarShaw-MT i am talking about this service https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CloudServiceARM

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/deploy-portal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also Search for that there is no document to create Azure Cloud Service (Extended Support) using terraform.

> Cloud Services (extended support) is a new Azure Resource Manager
> (ARM) based deployment model for Azure Cloud Services. Azure Cloud
> Services is a platform as a service (PaaS) offering that allows you to
> quickly deploy and manage powerful applications and services. It
> manages provisioning, load balancing, and health monitoring.

This is new Service in Azure so this might be the reason I think currently azurerm terraform does not cover extended version of Cloud Service feature. You can raise a discussion in Github for the same request.

**https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11234**